# MySQL BIT datatype turns always to 1

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing some unexpected behavior with MySQL BIT datatype. By executing the following PHP code:

```
$query="INSERT INTO REQUESTS_OFFERS (PROPOSAL,REQUESTS_REQUESTID,PERIOD)
  VALUES ('".$offer."','".$requestid."','".$periodkind."')";
```

period column which is of BIT data type is always turning to 1 even if PHP variable $periodkind equals to 0!!  I cannot explain that. If trying to change manually 1 to 0 inside MySQL there is no problem...

Do you have any idea why that happens?

Thank you very much

Comment: if you have a bit, why are you wrapping `'` around it like a string? Conceavably inserting the string `'0'` rather than the integer `0` could make MySQL store it as `1`...you'll have to test that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column is a BIT datatype, you don't have to wrap your var into " ' " because it will be interpreted as a string and you want a bit.

Try to remove single quotes and if it doesn't work, try to cast your $periodkind to a bool like this :

```
(bool)$periodkind
```

ONLY IF MySQL converts false to 0 and true to 1 in BIT datatype

Answer (score 1):

do you use PDO or mysqli? why don't you use statement prepare?

You must do that!

But quick fix for you I believe (remove single quotes around `periodkind`):

```
$query="INSERT INTO REQUESTS_OFFERS (PROPOSAL,REQUESTS_REQUESTID,PERIOD)
  VALUES ('".$offer."','".$requestid."',".$periodkind.")";
```

by the way your BIT type is **BIT(1)**?